# Global reduction of Hamiltonian with an integral of motion (Poincare' reduction)

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-mechanics

This question is related to a [previous one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333245/practical-example-of-hamiltonian-reduction); now I better understand the problem and I can more clearly state what is the question.

**Background**

I refer to the following concepts:

Liouville integrability: a Hamiltonian with $n$ degrees of freedom has $n$ independent integrals of motion in involution; we know that the Hamiltonian can be brought to the form $H(p_1, \dots, p_n)$ (i.e. independent on the $q$s) by a canonical transformation.

Poincare' reduction: the Hamiltonian has **one** integral of motion (just to simplify!); we can bring the Hamiltonian to the form $H(p_1, q_1, \dots, p_{n-1}, q_{n-1}, p_n)$ (i.e. we remove the dependence on one of the $q$s, $q_n$) by means of a canonical transformation.

**Global versus local**

There are examples of both operations (Liouville integration or Poincare' reduction) that are performed globally.

We also know that the Liouville integration is guaranteed to be feasible globally under a non-degeneracy condition (Arnold-Liouville theorem). Else, if the non-degenerasy condition is not met, the integrability is guaranteed only locally.

On the other hand, the feasibility of Poincare' reduction is discussed only locally (for what I've seen, e.g. Arnold, "Mathematical Aspects of Classical and Celestial Mechanics", proposition 3.2).

**What I'm asking**

I would like to know if there is any result which guarantees the global feasibility of the Poincare' reduction. This could possibly include a non-degeneracy condition (as in the case of Liouville's integration) or a wider range of forms of the reduced Hamiltonian.

Comment: In the case of a single integral (which i understand is what interests you) isn't the degeneracy condition of prop. 3.2, p.116, $dF(z)\neq 0$ for all points $z$ of the phase space manifold, what you are asking for?

Comment: Also: in the second paragraph of the background section you say "Poisson reduction". I guess you mean "Poincare reduction" ?

Comment: I fixed the errors, thank you for the help in both questions. For the suggestion $dF(z)\ne 0$ for all points $z$, on one side, I do not think that it works. I have a counter-example, in which $dF(z)\ne 0$ everywhere, but the reduction does not work. If you are interested I can show a document. Moreover, if you inspect the proof (of the rectification of the trajectory, as suggested by Arnold), you see that it is not enough to cover the space with the neighborhoods to make the property global.

Comment: ok! thanks for the feedback. unfortunately, i do not know more to say. If you can share the link you are mentioning (the counter-example) that would be great!

Comment: Here is the document: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7tbj3msltzr78cq/controesempio.pdf?dl=0 . I used your contribution in the initial part, so I would be pleased if you appreciate it and want to be a co-author. The last part is still not complete.

Comment: Doriano, thank you very much for the document and the proposal to be a co-author. I really appreciate that. However, i have to study the document to judge if my contribution could be important (to justify co-authorship). I'lll devote some time in it and will come back to you as soon as possible.

Comment: I have an updated version, but, for further discussion, please join this chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94648/global-poincare-reduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easier to think about this geometrically: suppose we have a function $F:M\to\mathbb{R}$ (where $M$ is your phase space) such that $\lbrace H, F\rbrace = 0$, and also the level sets $F^{-1}(c)$ are all (embedded) submanifolds of $M$. Then we can take $P_n=F$, and from that construct canonical coordinates $Q_i, P_i$. The fact that $\lbrace H, F\rbrace = 0$ means that $H$ is invariant under the flow produced by taking $F=P_n$ as the Hamiltonian. This flow maps $Q_n$ to $Q_n+t$, and preserves all other coordinates. Hence $H$ is independent of $Q_n$.

The requirement $dF \ne 0$ everywhere ensures that $F^{-1}(c)$ is actually an embedded submanifold for each $c$ (this is often referred to as the [Submersion Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)#Submersion_theorem)). I believe the reason your counterexample (linked in the chatroom) fails is that it does not satisfy this condition: the Henon-Heiles Hamiltonian $H$ has several points where $dH = 0$, even if you exclude the point $(q_1,q_2,p_1,p_2)=(0,0,0,0)$ (incidentally, these are the equilibrium points of the system).

Edit: I realise now I'm not really addressing your actual question, but more the counterexample (linked to in the chatroom). One issue with the discussion above is that the new canonical coordinates $Q_i, P_i$ are only defined locally in general, and you're correct in asserting that what you call Poincare reduction is really only a local construction. Marsden-Weinstein reduction (which is a global construction) would be applicable in the case that the space of trajectories $F^{-1}(c)/\mathbb{R}$ of the Hamiltonian $F$ in $F^{-1}(c)$ can be given a smooth structure such that $\pi:F^{-1}(c)\to F^{-1}(c)/\mathbb{R}$ is a submersion. One criterion for this is that the $\mathbb{R}$-action on $M$ determined by $F$ is [proper](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperGroupAction.html), but I'm not sure how useful this would be for you (sorry).

Comment: Thank you for your contribution! If I correctly understand, the condition that the gradient of $F$ does not vanish in $M$ implies that it can be taken equal to $P_n$. This is a quite hevy consequence, since it means that it has many functions in involution, such as all the $P$s and the $Q$s except $Q_n$. Is this correct? However, the idea of removing the "bad" points from $M$ leads me to think that there must be the condition that $M$ does not have "holes", such as the complementary space of $M$ is simply connected. Do you confirm the presence of this condition?

Comment: It's correct that this implies the other $P$s and $Q$s are in involution, but as I mentioned in the edit these are only locally defined functions in general. For example, in the extremely simple case of a 1D harmonic oscillator (with the origin removed), and taking $F=H=P_1$, the complementary coordinate $Q_1$ would be an angular variable, which is not defined globally. I'm not quite sure what you're asking in your second question, I'm afraid - perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: If you agree that the Poincare' method works only locally, wether $dF\ne 0$ on $M$ or not, then the question on the topology of $M$ does not matter. On the other hand, I would like to better understand the Marsden-Weinstein reduction. What does it say on the case of my counter-example? Can we apply it? And what is the form of the reduced system?

Comment: I'm not too knowledgeable about chaotic systems, but no, Marsden-Weinstein reduction isn't applicable in this case. The reason is that for Henon-Heiles, the space of trajectories $H^{-1}(E)/\mathbb{R}$ is not even a smooth manifold (some trajectories are quasiperiodic, some are homoclinic, some are dense in an open subset of the energy surface $H^{-1}(E)$). Your counter-example is a bit artificial, since you're essentially adding together two (non-coupled) Hamiltonian systems, and taking one system's Hamiltonian as your first integral. But the issue exists in the first system on its own.

Comment: Correction: I meant periodic, not quasiperiodic.

Comment: I was asking a reference, but saying that there are no solutions to the problem (to your knowledge) is equally helpful. Coming back to Poincare' reduction: your answer focus on proving that my counter-example is not valid. However, the counter-example was aimed at proving that the Poincare' reduction is not always feasible globally, which is also your opinion. On the other hand, you think that condition $dF\ne 0$, also if globally valid on $M$, is still not enough to guarantee the global feasibility. So, could you please clarify what is the rationale of your discussion of the counter-example?

Comment: I'm just trying to clarify for you what goes wrong in your counter-example, so you can have a better understanding of the issues involved. Except in very trivial examples, you won't be able to find global *functions* $Q_i, P_i$ satisfying your criteria. However, there is still a global *formulation* in some cases, corresponding to (a special case of) the hypothesis of the Marsden-Weinstein reduction: essentially that $F^{-1}(c)/\mathbb{R}$ is a manifold (see Francois Ziegler's answer). In your counter-example, there are neither global functions nor a global formulation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sorry for bothering you again. I see that my counter-example does not satisfy $dF\ne 0$ in some ponts, which is required for the local viability of Poincare' reduction. Question 1) Do you claim that, under the condition $dF\ne 0$ on $M$, then the Poincare' reduction is globally feasible? Question 2) In my counter-example, I can define a suitable $M$ without points such that $dF=0$. What prevents me to use the theorem of the previous question (1)?

Comment: Btw, I also have a question 3): what are the points $c$ for which $dF=0$ for the H-H Hamiltonian, except the origin $(0,0,0,0)$? According to a simple calculation. the only equilibrium point should be the origin.

Comment: Taking as you do $H= p_1^2/2+p_2^2/2+q_1^2/2+q_2^2/2+q_1^2q_2-q_2^3/3$, we get
$dH = p_1\,dp_1 + p_2\,dp_2 + q_1(1+2q_2)\,dq_1 + (q_1^2+q_2(1-q_2))\,dq_2$.
This has equilibrium points at $(q_1,q_2) = (0,0), (0,1)$, and $(\sqrt{3}/2,-1/2)$ (all with $(p_1,p_2)=(0,0)$).

Comment: I see! But they are saddle points on the border of the potential hole. I would take $M$ such that the trajectories are in the potential hole (roughly with $H$<0.167) and exclude the origin. This $M$ would apply to my question (2), if the answer to question (1) is "yes".

Comment: Sorry, I missed your first question. No, even excluding points where $dH=0$, there isn't a global formulation in general, since the space of trajectories $H^{-1}(E)/\mathbb{R}$ cannot necessarily be given a manifold structure. I don't know much about the Henon-Heiles system, but this seems to be the case there (many of its trajectories wind densely through a subset of the energy surface $H^{-1}(E)$, as seen in the Poincare sections for the system).

Comment: Summarizing this interesting discussion: 1) You agree with my statement in the question that the Poincare' reduction cannot be always performed globally; 2) Provided that $M$ is correctly defined, my counter-example is a valid example that the Poincare' reduction cannot be done globally; 3) the Marsden-Weinstein reduction does not apply to cases such as my counter-example; 4) you are not aware of other reductions that can apply. If this is correct, could you please slightly modify your answer in this direction, so that I can put a + on it? Thanks!

Comment: I selected this as my preferred answer (and thus I awarded the bounty) although, for understanding the answer, it is necessary to carefully read all the comments.